# DocsList File getContentAsString() missing unicode characters

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to import a CSV file with french accents using Google App Script, reading the file using the getContentAsString() and then processing it into a Google Spreadsheet. It would seems the unicode characters are send back as garbage.

After investigation, it would seems getContentAsString() open files using UTF-8. This cause problems when the file is created using Western Mac OS Roman or Western Windows Latin 1 - default encoding on older Excel when exporting CSV.

Any suggestion on how to circumvent this problem?

> Example: �quipement should be Équipement

```
function Test() {
  var filename = 'BV_period_2.csv';
  var files = DocsList.getFiles();
  var csvFile = "";

  for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
    if (files[i].getName() == filename ) {
      csvFile = files[i].getContentAsString(); //csvFile will have �     
      break;
    }
  }

  var csvData = CSVToArray(csvFile, ",");
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TestBV');
  ...
```

Comment: Where do you get these bad characters? In the spreadsheet itself?  Is it the same in the logger? What are the Locale settings of your sheet?  French?  US?  Could you post the code you use to import the CSV file?

Comment: After investigation, it would seems getContentAsString() open files using **UTF-8**. This cause problems when the file is created using **Western Mac OS Roman** or **Western Windows Latin 1** - default encoding on older Excel when exporting CSV.

Comment: The DocList services was deprecated. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/sunset

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can optionally choose the charset. Here's a UTF-16 example.

```
DocsList.getFileById(<some id>).getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-16")
```

Comment: Corey, thanks for the suggestion, it works. Your method correctly import a CSV file encoded in Western Mac OS Roman to UTF-8.
**Note**: the documentation do not indicate we can add a parameter for the type of characters encoding. [getDataAsString](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/class_blob#getDataAsString)