# The reference to entity "F" must end with the ';' delimiter. [replacing & with &amp; did not solve the issue]

Tags: xml, google-apps-script

```
   var url = 'http://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=TSAL[t.t_eq_s]![T.E_EQ_N]![T.E_NE_O]![as0,20,tv_gt_40000]![th0_gt_am1,253,th]&report=predefall';
   var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText(); 
   var xml = XmlService.parse(text);
```

Any ideas to why I get the error message mentioned in the title? 
I have already replaced '&' with '& amp;' in 'url'.
I suspect that it might be '[', ']' and/or '!' that is causing the problem.
I have read through other posts on this type of problem, but was unable to crack the problem myself - hope that someone can help me.

**UPDATE**
With the input from Michael Kay I went back and read some more posts - in particular these:

[Character encoding issue when using Google Apps Script to extract data from web page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33792859/character-encoding-issue-when-using-google-apps-script-to-extract-data-from-web)

[What is the best way to parse html in google apps script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19455158/what-is-the-best-way-to-parse-html-in-google-apps-script)

-and decided to go for a more simple solution (because I only need the symbols from the webpage). So my code ended up looking like this:

```
var url = 'http://stockcharts.com/def/servlet/SC.scan?s=TSAL[t.t_eq_s]![T.E_EQ_N]![T.E_NE_O]![as0,20,tv_gt_40000]![th0_gt_am1,253,th]&report=predefall';
var text = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url).getContentText();
text = text.substring(text.search('<tbody>'),text.search('</tbody>'));
var srchstr = 'symbol=';
while (text.search(srchstr) > -1){    
  var start = text.search(srchstr) + srchstr.length;
  text = text.substring(start, text.length);
  var end = text.search('"');
  var symbol = text.substring(0, end);
  Logger.log(symbol);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it's the URL that's the problem: it's the text that's retrieved by dereferencing the URL (the result of `getContentText()`), which you haven't shown us.

Comment: Thanks Michael for your input - I managed to come up with a solution (see my updated post).

Comment: That's a pretty awful solution. The XML parser is telling you that the input is invalid XML, and you've solved the problem by bypassing the XML parser. At best I would call this a workaround. When you have bad data, you need to find out where it's coming from and fix it at source.