# Google Apps Script: How to fix "content is not allowed in prolog"

Tags: javascript, xml, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to parse the following XML file with Google Apps Script `XmlService`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
     <Report Major="1" Minor="0" Revision="1">
        <CoIDs>  ….
```

Code snippet:

```
function parse(txt) {
  var document = XmlService.parse(txt);
  var root = document.getRootElement();
  //...
}
```

When running the script, I get the error message: `Content is not allowed in prolog`.

Is there a issue with the format of the XML file?
How can I parse this file with Google Apps Script?

### Update

I managed to solve the issue by opening the file and saving it again as `UTF-8` document with Apple TextEdit. Is there any "automatic" (or code-based) way to convert a non-`UTF 8` (presumably `UTF-16` document) to `UTF-8` before reading it with Google Apps Script?

Comment: Check whether the xml file has been saved with a BOM.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is possible to choose the char set of a file when you open it in your drive, I found this info in a post answer by a Google engineer (Corey G) so even if I didn't test it I think he's a trustful source :-) .

The post is [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266469/docslist-file-getcontentasstring-missing-unicode-characters/11315298#11315298) and the code goes as follow:

```
DocsList.getFileById(<some id>).getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-16");// replace by the Charset you want... UFT-8 for example.
```

So I guess it's worth trying...
Let us know if it solves your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this issue too, I fixed it by removing the BOM (Byte order mark) from the document in my editor. This fixed the problem for me. I guess the parser sees the BOM as content or something.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I've downloaded Notepad++ and configured the encoding to 'Encode in UTF-8'. You can find it by opening your xml file and selecting Encoding tab -> 'Encode in UTF-8'.

It'll be effective for all xml files in the future.

Hope it finds you well.