# Parse UTF-8-BOM xml files using XmlService Google App script

Tags: xml, google-apps-script, utf-8

I'm currently trying to extract the content of xml files located on my google drive to a spreadsheet format.
I made a function that parse an xml and extract the data I need to a sheet of the current spreadsheet.
My function works fine and make the job, I'm using UTF-8 encoded xml files.

My problem comes when I parse an xml encoded in UTF-8-BOM. The `XmlService.parse(data)` doesn't work anymore :
I'm having the error `Exception: Error on line 1: Content is not allowed in prolog.` on the line `var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);`

I tried to modify following line according to an answer i saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11266469/docslist-file-getcontentasstring-missing-unicode-characters/11315298#11315298).

```
var data = DriveApp.getFileById(xml).getBlob().getDataAsString("UTF-8-BOM");
```

But I have the following error : `Exception: Invalid argument: UTF-8-BOM` on this line.

Do you have any idea of how i could make it parse my UTF-8-BOM xml?

By the way, even if the xml file is encoded in UTF-8-BOM, the first line is :
`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>`

Here is my code if needed, it works for UTF-8 xml files.

```
function parseBasicXML(xml,sheet) {
  
var data = DriveApp.getFileById(xml).getBlob().getDataAsString();
var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);
var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
  
var items = root.getChildren("ZZZZ");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var items2 = items[i].getChild("AAAA");
  var items3 = items[i].getChild("YYYY")
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(root.getAttribute("XXX").getValue()); 
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(items[i].getAttribute("BBBB").getValue());  
  if(items2 != null){
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 9).setValue(items2.getAttribute("WWWW").getValue());
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 13).setValue(items2.getAttribute("TTTT").getValue());}
  if(items3 != null){sheet.getRange(i+2,7).setValue(items3.getAttribute("DDDD").getValue());
                     sheet.getRange(i+2,8).setValue(items3.getAttribute("OOOO").getValue());}
  
  }
}
```

Here is a sample of an xml structure I use :

```
<RRRR Version="NA" Speed="100000" Gap="4" ZZZZ="AAAA" OOOO="N/A" Comments="">
    <Message LLLL="XXXX" DDDD="XXXX" SSM_00="XXXX" S_01="XXXX" S_10="XXXX" S_11="XXXX" SSSS="XXXX">
        <TTTT>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="XXXX" BBBB="XXX"/>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="XXXX" BBBB="XXX"/>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="XXXX" BBBB="XXX"/>
        </TTTT>
        <SSS>
            <VVVV>00</VVVV>
        </SSS>
    </Message>
    <Message LLLL="XXXX" DDDD="XXXX" S_00="XXXX" S_01="XXXX" S_10="XXXX" S_11="XXXX" SSSS="XXXX">
        <TTTT>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="" BBBB="XXX"/>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="" BBBB="XXX"/>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="" BBBB="XXX"/>          
        </TTTT>
        <SSS>
            <VVVV>00</VVVV>
        </SSS>
    </Message>
    <Message LLLL="XXXX" DDDD="XXXX" S_00="XXXX" S_01="XXXX" S_10="XXXX" S_11="XXXX" SSSS="XXXX">
        <TTTT>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="" BBBB="XXX"/>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="" BBBB="XXX"/>
            <DDDD NNNN="XXXX" DDDD="" BBBB="XXX"/>
        </TTTT>
        <SSS>
            <VVVV>00</VVVV>
        </SSS>
    </Message>  
</RRRR>
```

I made the following code so you can test it when you encode the xml file as UTF-8 and UTF-8-BOM : (the `xml` data correspond to the ID of the xml file on your dirve, the `sheet` the sheet name you want your datas to be exported)

```
function parseSampleXML(xml,sheet) {  
var data = DriveApp.getFileById(xml).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Added
var xmlDocument=XmlService.parse(data);
var root=xmlDocument.getRootElement();
  
var items = root.getChildren("Message");

for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
  var items3 = items[i].getChild("SSSS")
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 1).setValue(root.getAttribute("ZZZZ").getValue()); 
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 4).setValue(items[i].getAttribute("LLLL").getValue());  
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 5).setValue(items[i].getAttribute("DDDD").getValue());
  sheet.getRange(i+2, 6).setValue(items[i].getAttribute("SSSS").getValue());
  if(items3 != null){sheet.getRange(i+2,7).setValue(items3.getValue());}
  
   }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Victor

Comment: Could you please give more details on `doesn't work anymore`? Are you getting any error? If that's the case, where? Is `data` retrieving the content successfully?

Comment: I edited my post. It seems that data isn't retrieving the content.

Comment: Can you provide the sample file of utf-8 with BOM? If you cannot do it, please don't worry.

Comment: @Tanaike I'm affraid that I can't, I'm working on sensitive datas ... Note that an UTF-8 encoded file is parsed normally, but when I encode this same file in UTF-8-BOM I have the errors I described. I have tried with many different structured xml files and it doesn't matter, I always have the same errors :(

Comment: Thank you for your response. I understand about your situation.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, this problem does not only happen with one file right? Could you provide a sample file of UTF-8 with BOM which does not contain any sensitive data, in which this behaviour can be reproduced?

Comment: I edited my post. You can now find a sample of an xml file I use. I also made a code so you can test by yourself with the xml I provided. Try to encode it in UTF-8, it will work. But you will have the same errors as me if you encode the xml in UTF-8-BOM (I use Notepad++ to encode the files).

Comment: Thank you for providing the additional information. I noticed it just now. I'm sorry. From your additional information, I proposed a modification point as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If that was not the result you expect, I apologize.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [this information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark), in order to retrieve the values from the data with UTF-8 BOM, I would like to propose the following modification.

When your bottom script in your question is modified, it becomes as follows.

#### From:

```
var data = DriveApp.getFileById(xml).getBlob().getDataAsString(); // Added
```

#### To:

```
var [,,,...bytes] = DriveApp.getFileById(xml).getBlob().getBytes();
var data = Utilities.newBlob(bytes).getDataAsString();
```

or

```
var bytes = DriveApp.getFileById(xml).getBlob().getBytes();
bytes.splice(0, 3);
var data = Utilities.newBlob(bytes).getDataAsString();
```

- In this modification, 3 bytes are removed from the top of the data of UTF-8 BOM. By this, I think that your script will work.

#### Note:

- In my environment, I could replicate your issue. And also, I could confirm that when above modification is used, your script worked.

#### References:

- [Byte order mark (BOM)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark)
- [getBytes()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob.html#getbytes)
- [newBlob(data)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/utilities/utilities#newblobdata)

Comment: Thank you very much! Your modification works fine, I can now use my script on UTF-8-BOM files.Removing the 3 bytes the BOM add is pretty clever, well done :)

Comment: @Victor_exo Thank you for replying and testing it. I'm glad your issue was resolved. By your additional information, I could replicate your situation and think of the solution. Thank you, too.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://gist.github.com/antic183/619f42b559b78028d1fe9e7ae8a1352d) worked well for me.

```
if (res.charCodeAt(0) === 0xFEFF) {
  res = res.substr(1);
}
```